# Java: simulate keypresses when mouse clicked?

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot

So, I'm fairly new to programming and I like to fiddle with it and one day my friend asked me to make a program where when you click, "ctrl" and "s" would be "pressed". I looked at lots of forums trying to make a functional code but, since I'm new to Java, I only got separate pieces of codes and threw it all together.

My code looks like this:

```
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;  
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.awt.Robot;   
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {  
    public static void main(String args[]) {  
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("press any key to exit.");  
        keyboard.next();
        System.exit(0);
    }  
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {  
        try {  
            Robot robot = new Robot();  
            // Simulate a key press  
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);  
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);  
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);   
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);  
    } catch (AWTException e) {        
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: You needs GUI to attach your mouse listener to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program has no GUI and, therefore, nothing to invoke your mouse listener. The code within the listener appears correct, all you need to do is search for how to create a basic GUI and add the mouse listener to it so you get the results you want.

Comment: So a GUI is necessary? The idea of the program is if you click anywhere "ctrl + s" is pressed, is it possible to make an invisible square covering the entire screen?

Comment: A basic version is possible (search for it), but you won't be able to simply lock out the taskbar on Windows or anything like that without getting much more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may help you to handle Ctrl + S

```
public class SwingApp1 extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
public SwingApp1() {
    setSize(500, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setBackground(Color.blue);
    addKeyListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingApp1 main = new SwingApp1();
    main.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent evt) {

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    System.out.println("Pressed=>" + e.getKeyCode());
    if (e.getKeyCode() == 83) {
        System.out.println("Pressed Ctrl + S");
    } // Ctrl + S
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
}}
```